# Searching string in a webpage using regular expression on Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to search if there is `/[some names]/unfollow` in a webpage. And I have very little experience on regular expressions. This is what I worked for now.

```
import urllib
import re

page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.domain.com').read()
results = re.findall('/[\w]*/unfollow', page)
for i in results:
    print i
```

But the code above not printing anything. Am I doing it wrong? If so, I really need help from you guys

Thanks

Comment: do you just want the words before /unfollow?

Comment: that regex finds nothing on your page, anyway I suggest you use beautifulsoup to parse a web page, using re is not a great idea.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes I just want the words before `/unfollow`. In some cases, I have to go through 480 webpages using `while` loop. I think that's time consuming. Is using beautifulsoup making it more time efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findall function should be,

```
results = re.findall(r'\/[^\/]*\/unfollow', page)
```

It will findall all the strings which are in `/some names/unfollow` format.

**Explanation:**

- `\/` Matches a  literal `/` symbol.
- `[^\/]*` Matches any character not of `/` zero or more times.
- `\/unfollow` Matches the string `/unfollow`

Comment: If you want only the words before `/unfollow` then try `m = re.findall(r'\/([^\/]*)\/unfollow', str)` code.